# Initialization of std::function does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

GameObject class .h + .cpp:

```
typedef std::function<void(GameObject* triggerobject, GameObject* otherobject, TriggerAction action)> PhysicsCallback;

    void GameObject::OnTrigger(GameObject* triggerobject, GameObject* otherobject, TriggerAction action)
    {
        if (m_OnTriggerCallback)
            m_OnTriggerCallback(triggerobject, otherobject, action);
    }

    void GameObject::SetOnTriggerCallBack(PhysicsCallback callback)
    {
        m_OnTriggerCallback = callback;
    }
```

Other class:

```
m_pSphere->SetOnTriggerCallBack(*pCbObj);
m_pSphere->OnTrigger(m_pWallLeft, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0));
```

I figured to use the OnTrigger() function I had to set m_OnTriggerCallback. When I tried to pass corresponding arguments however I got really stuck. It seems almost impossible to initalize PhysicsCallback without getting compiler errors.

I tried:
`std::function<void(GameObject* triggerobject, GameObject* otherobject, GameObject::TriggerAction action)> *obj;
*obj = (m_pWallRight, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0));`

But no luck. *obj doesn't accept any arguments. These following lines give the same errors:

```
GameObject::PhysicsCallback *pCbObj; = new GameObject::PhysicsCallback(new std::function<void()>()); //term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
    GameObject::PhysicsCallback *pCbObj = new GameObject::PhysicsCallback((m_pWallRight, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0)));
```

And this line `*pCbObj = GameObject::PhysicsCallback(m_pWallRight, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0));`gives this intellisense error:
http://puu.sh/gi29n/95f0f7855b.png

I'm really confused, how to use the SetOnTriggerCallBack function?

Comment: You should add the prototype of `GameObject::TriggerAction` here.

Comment: `std::function` must be initialized with some *callable*, something that can be called as if it were a function. Your callable needs to be a function, functor ... something that takes arguments of types `GameObject*, GameObject*, TriggerAction` and returns `void`. You're trying to create `PhysicsCallback` with this expression `(m_pWallRight, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0))` which isn't a callable. And what is this - `PhysicsCallback(new std::function<void()>())`. Intellisense errors don't mean much, you should copy-paste the error messages the compiler produces.

Comment: This is the corresponding compiler error message: 'std::function<void (GameObject *,GameObject *,GameObject::TriggerAction)>::function' : none of the 10 overloads could convert all the argument types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lambda I was able to create an parameter that was acceptable for the compiler:

```
GameObject::PhysicsCallback trigger = [=](GameObject* triggerobject, GameObject* otherobject, GameObject::TriggerAction action){};
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
m_pSphere->OnTrigger(m_pWallLeft, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0));
```

is actually calling `GameObject::TriggerAction` with `0` as argument. Then, it passes its result.

What is `GameObject::TriggerAction`? Is it a static method ? It should be because, otherwise, you have either to `std::bind` it to an [object instance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) or to apply it directly.

Comment: TriggerAction is an Enum, nothing too special about it. It works fine as argument in other function calls.

Comment: What is `pCbObj` in `m_pSphere->SetOnTriggerCallBack(*pCbObj);` ? It could help us undestand.

Comment: pCbObj is the PhysicsCallback (object?) pointer I try to pass on as argument. I'm not really good at namings and definitions. If it would be possible I'd pass the 3 arguments m_pWallRight, m_pSphere, GameObject::TriggerAction(0) on but the compiler starts complaining because I don't know how to melt these in an std::function as one argument

Comment: Show us more code, please ! We don't have enough information from what you quoted.

Comment: Alright, this is my scene I'm working at: http://pastebin.com/1FB1M3FZ, this is part of the engine: http://pastebin.com/h6bAmPkm